# TensorFlow Object Detection Model demo not working accurately

Tags: tensorflow

I was trying out the new tensorflow object detection api, however the demo doesn't work as accurately as shown in their examples on a pre-trained model.

I used the example located at: [Tutorial/Example on API Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb)

The results as shown on their github page are like this: [Image showing demo results](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/raw/master/object_detection/g3doc/img/kites_detections_output.jpg), whereas my results on the pre-trained model looks like this: [My results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pp9B.jpg).

I followed the installation instructions as described on the Github. Anyone know why the discrepancy between the tutorial example and my results on a pre-trained model?

Comment: How did you train your model?

Comment: I used a pre-trained model provided in the demo. The example linked in the question description has a section of code that downloads and loads a pre-trained "frozen tensorflow model".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IPython noteboook by default uses our SSD Mobilenet detector, which does not generate the best results, but is one of our quickest models. The image on our Github page was generated using a different model. Consider experimenting with other models from our [model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use visualize util, it clip detected objects, try to use raw data from output tensors and use your own threshold algorithm.
And also all this demo models were trained not very intensive, cause by default such models should give mAP about 80% and not 30%.

Answer (score 0):

You can use model "faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_2017_11_08" instead of "ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_08"